# Why does my element is not visible with z-index 10000

Tags: html, css, ytplayer

I am developping a website with youtube videos, and I am using mb.YTPlayer plugin. You can see it here : http://orthopluss.fr/test/index.html#prestations

There are two arrows, one on the right, one on the left, which I would like to put ON the video. For example, if I take the left arrow and remove the margin-left, the arrow is positioned behing the video.
I tried adding a z-index : 10000 on the #timelapse-prev button but it doesn't get the button in front of the video.

I have been to do it on the demo plugin page (using the developper tools) : http://pupunzi.com/mb.components/mb.YTPlayer/demo/demo_as_player.html so I am assuming that's something from my page that causes an issue...

I tried many things (setting other z-index differentely) but it has no effect. Do you have an idea what would cause such a behavior ?

Thanks !!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: please add your code

Comment: maybe you set `position: fixed;` to your buttons. This may cause z-index to not work on them

Comment: Try inspecting the button element (`F12`, click on the pointer icon, and click on the video, the hover over or click the button tag, which I assume is next to the player tag)

Comment: Try pulling the arrows outside the parent structure, maybe they're inheriting z-index from a parent.

Comment: Inspecting may show if `z-index` is overriden

Comment: Use a `position` that is different than `static` like `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed` combined with a `z-index` value.

Comment: This was too easy, I just had to add the position : relative with the z-index and it is fine ! (Sorry I didn't post better code, I thought the link was easier for debugging)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Mark Perera and Vincent G :

The answer is that I have to add a specific position property.
Adding position:relative and z-index:10000 is enough to make the element on top of the video !

Sorry for the trouble ! 
Thank you all !